# Centering subfloat caption with subfig package

Tags: captions, subfloats

A footnote on page 12 of the [`subfig` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/subfig/subfig.pdf) says in part:

> Note that the ‘width’ may be larger than the width of the
>   sub-float body, or equivalently, the ‘width’ may be negative to provide more room for a caption if the
>   sub-float body is small. The box holding the caption is centered relative to the sub-float body.

I must not be understanding something.

First, by looking at Figure 91 on page 35, don't they mean to say that you can set the `margin` to a negative value in order to get a caption that is wider than (and centered relative to) the sub-float body?

Even if this is right, I can't get a simple example to work.  See my MWE below.

What am I doing wrong?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
 \centering
 \subfloat[very long subfloat caption]{
  \framebox[3cm][c]{
   subfloat body
  }
 }
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[ht]
 \centering
 \captionsetup[subfloat]{width=-2cm}
 \subfloat[very very long subfloat caption]{
  \framebox[3cm][c]{
   subfloat body
  }
 }
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[ht]
 \centering
 \captionsetup[subfloat]{margin=-2cm}
 \subfloat[very very long subfloat caption]{
  \framebox[3cm][c]{
   subfloat body
  }
 }
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Better using `subcaption`, anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You can fool `subfig` letting it think that the subfloat is, e.g., `\textwidth` wide, by inserting the subfloat body in a box of that width.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
 \centering
 \subfloat[very very very very very long subfloat caption]{%
  \makebox[\textwidth]{\framebox[3cm][c]{subfloat body}}%
 }
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Yes, thanks. That has been my workaround for a few years now. I am specifically wondering about the question I asked.

Comment: @TysonWilliams I don't think it can be done any better...

Comment: Yes, I agree that the output of your workaround looks perfect. That is why I also have been using that workaround for years now. I really am just trying to understand this footnote in the `subfig` documentation.